# How to download files got from input type="file" in asp?

Tags: asp-classic

I am just a newbie with the asp, but I am creating a website that download images from input type="file". I also want to know how to make a code that makes the targeted folder to be the default location of the downloading file. The location of the folder is "C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/Facts and Trivia/Data Pictures". Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a component like [ASPUpload](http://www.aspupload.com/) or [Pure ASP Upload](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pure-asp-upload.htm). Their sites are well documented and should provide the answers you need.